# Meaning of "Einpreßrate" or "Einpreßmenge"

Tags: meaning

In a reservoir engineering context, what does *Einpreßrate* or *Einpreßmenge* mean?

Comment: The "Neue Rechtschreibung" let you spell it as "Einpressrate"/"Einpressmenge".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*injection rate* or *injected amount*

Maybe the context is fracking here. Independently of that, the terms concern the amount of fluid that is injected (by pressure) per unit of time or the total amount, respectively.